# Does DotNetBrowser support WebAuthn / PublicKeyCredentials?

Tags: webauthn, dotnetbrowser

As far as I can tell from my initial attempts, I don't think it does. I can't find any mentions on the interwebz, or in the dotnetbrowser documentation.

Logs seem to imply some failure that might be related, but can't be sure.

```
2022-07-20T14:17:08.4630114+01:00  Information  Browser - [Load Requests: Browser] Ignore load result 'Completed' caused by NavigationFinished(Committed == true && SameDocument == true) for BrowserId{Uuid: adae58b8-b3ed-41b0-8473-ed4b394cc609; } [EventQueue : LoadResult Events Thread]
2022-07-20T14:17:08.4630114+01:00  Information      IPC - [Stream   0061 RECV] Navigation.WhenLoadFinished:13 [LoadFinished{BrowserId: BrowserId{Uuid: adae58b8-b3ed-41b0-8473-ed4b394cc609; }; }] []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.3954498+01:00        Error  Process - [25592:32640:0720/141709.395:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:17:09.394] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F) []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.4004513+01:00        Error  Process - [25592:32640:0720/141709.400:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:17:09.399] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F) []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.4384470+01:00        Error  Process - [25592:32640:0720/141709.438:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:17:09.438] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1205 Getting Radio failed. Chrome will be unable to change the power state by itself. []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.4614470+01:00        Error  Process - [25592:32640:0720/141709.461:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:17:09.460] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1283 OnPoweredRadioAdded(), Number of Powered Radios: 1 []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.4614470+01:00        Error  Process - [25592:32640:0720/141709.461:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:17:09.461] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1298 OnPoweredRadiosEnumerated(), Number of Powered Radios: 1 []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.4964475+01:00        Error  Process - [0720/141709.496:INFO:browsercore.cc(98)] BrowserCore::Init []
2022-07-20T14:17:09.5844490+01:00        Error  Process - [0720/141709.584:INFO:browsercore.cc(98)] BrowserCore::Init []
```

Has anyone achieved this, or not? Any further information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAuthn support is planned to be added in DotNetBrowser 2.16. It is mentioned in this [Tweet](https://twitter.com/DotNetBrowser/status/1549757853757571072?s=20&t=voeZG_CCxitEnL5XwFdzhQ).

Comment: Ah. The one place I didn't look. Twitter being the darkest place of the human soul. I was hoping they would have some kind of roadmap on their website, but no.

Comment: The roadmap is available in [DotNetBrowser Help Center](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/roadmap/)